# How to display only those columns in the gridview according to which dropdownlist the user selects

Tags: asp.net

For example i have three dropdownlists and the the user selects Say Name and PIN dropdownlist i want results that match the two to be displayed not any other what should I do?

Please help! :/

**EDIT:**

What i want to do is based on what dropdown list the user makes the selection from i want to display only those columns in the gridview on the next page and two fields name and pin corresponding to those rows will always be displayed ... if i try permutaion combinations i would have to make 81 sql queries. What should I do?

Comment: You need to give some sample. From the title it looks you want to display dynamic columns, but from your description looks like you want to display records based on search fields.

Answer (score 0):

Each column has a Visible attribute; one approach could be to bind the entire list of columns, and show/hide only the columns you want to show.  Alternatively, you could dynamically add the BoundField columns dependant on the selection.

HTH.